# App Engine Dev App Server doesn't update in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, devserver

I'm using Eclipse Java EE and I'm developing a google app-engine application using java and I'm using following Run configurations to run the application on localhost.

Base directory : `${project_loc}`

Goals: `appengine:devserver`

Maven runtime : External `C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5`

When I run the application using above configuration eclipse says that It is running (as the following)

```
[INFO] Jan 12, 2015 4:29:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8080
[INFO] Jan 12, 2015 4:29:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
[INFO] INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
[INFO] Jan 12, 2015 4:29:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: Module instance default is running at http  :  //  localhost : 8080/
[INFO] Jan 12, 2015 4:29:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http : // localhost : 8080 / _ ah / admin
[INFO] Jan 12, 2015 9:59:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

But when I type `localhost:8080` on the browser it says "This webpage is not available" (using chrome or any other)
But once I deploy the app on google appspot, the localhost:8080 shows my application but every time the changes I made won't appear unless I deploy the app to the appspot.

and when I started a new project and run it on the localhost It shows my previous application

However the application runs fine on appspot.

I think something wrong with the devserver (It doesn't update correctly) and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `mvn clean install` before `mvn appengine:devserver`

Answer (score 4):

When I type 127.0.0.1:8080 on the browser insted of localhost:8080, dev server runs just fine.